# Is opIndexAssign possible in C++?

Tags: c++, d

The [D Programming Language Version 2](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/) has a [nifty method to overload an expression like this](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/operatoroverloading.html#Assignment):

```
classInstance[someName] = someValue;
```

Or as D Function defined in [this little example](http://codepad.org/UV1Wsrdt):

```
ref Map opIndexAssign(ref const(ValueT) value, ref const(NameT) name)
{
    this.insert(name, value);
    return this;
}
```

Is this possible in C++ (ideally without using the STL)? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, you would use a proxy object as the return type of `operator[]`; that object will have a custom `operator=` defined.  The `vector<bool>` specialization in the C++ Standard Library uses a proxy to get the behavior you are looking for.  The proxy-based solution isn't as transparent as the D version, though.  The code is something like:

```
class proxy;

class my_map {
  public:
  proxy operator[](const key_type& k);
  // Rest of class
};

class proxy {
  my_map& m;
  key_type k;
  friend class my_map;
  proxy(my_map& m, const key_type& k): m(m), k(k) {}

  public:
  operator value_type() const {return m.read(k);}
  proxy& operator=(const value_type& v) {m.write(k, v); return *this;}
};

proxy my_map::operator[](const key_type& k) {
  return proxy(*this, k);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I was actually able to (almost) entirely mimic the syntax in the D code, although this code uses iterator abuse (but mainly just to show how it's done): http://codepad.org/YK6uDHDq -- wish I could upvote twice!

Answer (score 3):

Not being familiar with D, I'm going to have to assume that your first code snippet ends up calling `opIndexAssign` with `value = someValue` and `name = someName`?

If so, it can be done in C++, but not in such a simple manner. You could overload the `[]` operator, and return a proxy object with a custom `=` operator as follows (very basic, contrived example):

```
class MyProxy
{
    public:
        MyProxy (int& ref) : valueRef(ref) { }
        MyProxy& operator = (int value) { valueRef = value; return *this; }
    private:
        int& valueRef;
};

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyProxy operator [] (std::string name);
    private:
        int myVal;
};

MyProxy& MyClass::operator [] (std::string name)
{
    if (name.compare("myVal"))
        return MyProxy(myVal);

    ...
}

int main ( )
{
    MyClass mc;

    mc["myVal"] = 10; // Sets mc.myVal to 10
}
```

I'd like to strongly stress that the above is not very pretty/well formed code, just an illustration. It has not been tested.

**EDIT:** Too quick for me Jeremiah!!!